# Send String array from Activity to Service without intent

Tags: android

i want to send data that reside in the Activity file and extends service that receive data how is it Possible i dont want to use Intent here show me the way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your service runs in the **the same process** as your activity you can use:

- Intents - the best and recommended way. Why you don't want to use them?
- Static variables
- Shared preferences
- Database

If your service runs in a **different process** than your activity:

- http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/android/devguide/guide/developing/tools/aidl.html
- http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/aidl.html